# Comic book with a crossbow that fired a 'bolt' that unfolds mid-air into a horizontal sword/knife-like projectile

Tags: story-identification, comics

When I was younger (8 to 14 years ago, roughly) I read a comic book that I distinctly remember one thing from: a particular weapon.

It was a crossbow that fired a 'bolt' that unfolds mid-air into a horizontal sword/knife-like projectile which then proceeds to decapitate the opponent. After unfolding, the blade flew almost like an airplane, albeit a very sharp one that will cut whatever it makes contact with. I made a very crude illustration of how I remember the bolt being fired and unfolding:

[image: Diagram of how the projectile unfolded]

Other than that I remember that it was definitely set in a fantasy or sci-fi world, not current day Earth. I don't remember if the comic book was English or Dutch, it could be either. I do remember that it was in color.

Comment: *Punisher: War Journal* and its "gun that shoots swords" has been ruled out. Not fantasy, more stabby than slicey. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT4nr.jpg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vicente Segrelles, [El Mercenario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Mercenario) (The Mercenary)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes!  This is it!

Comment: That is freaking _cool_. Does the weapon have a particular name?